# Connecting to WooCommerce from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, oauth, woocommerce

I'm trying to retrieve products from my WooCommerce store using javascript code.

Doing this:

```
var result = OAuthSimple().sign({
                            path:'http://www.********.com/wp-json/wc/v1/products/', 
                            parameters: {encodeSignature: true},
                            signatures: {
                                      consumer_key:'ck_fcf30797c*******', 
                                      shared_secret:'cs_f4866d5d**********'
                                      }
                            });

location.href=result.signed_url;
```

I get this:

```
{"code":"woocommerce_rest_authentication_error","message":"Invalid signature - the given signature does not match.","data":{"status":401}}
```

The OAuthSimple code get from here: http://unitedheroes.net/OAuthSimple/

Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For those who has the same problem, in my case I have to call the version 2 of the API, I mean:

```
path:'http://www.********.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products/'
```

And there is a problem with the nounce key too... the OAuthSimple script give a 25 character string and it is necessary a 6 character string.

And it works.